# event onmouseover : function launched many times when a <div> includes a <div>

Tags: javascript, html, mouseevent, onmouseover

I have a javascript event onmouseover which is linked to a `<div>` called div1. As soons as the mouse enter the `<div>`, it writes something into the console. Right.

If i include an other `<div>` called div2 into the first one, the problem is that the event will be launched at each time the mouse goes from the first into the second, without escaping from div1. The event should be launched only one time, when the mouse enters div1

The code is pretty simple and can be tested [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6pTKm/) (please open a js console and put your mouse between red and blue)

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        #div1{
            position : absolute ;
            top: 100px;
            left: 100px;
            width : 200px;
            height : 200px; 
            background : red;
        }
        #div2{
            position : absolute ;
            top: 10px;
            left: 10px;
            width : 100px;
            height : 100px; 
            background : blue;
        }
    </style>        
</head>

<body> 
    <div id="div1"  >
        <div id="div2">          
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

<script>
    var div1 = document.getElementById('div1');
    div1.onmouseover = function(){
    console.log('Function launched!');
    };
</script>

</html>
```

In my website, it sends an AJAX request at each event... so it involves to many data transfer.

Answer (score 0):

Use next(), previous() methods or use nth-child or nth-of-type. Thanks and Good luck

Comment: You mean, I must list all elements into my div1 and write an event function on each?

Comment: If you are trying to add more in <div id="div1"></div> use the nth-child to indicate the div number. Like nth-child(1).

Comment: Please be more precise, what should i do with the new child? I don't understand.

Comment: <script>
    var div1 = document.getElementById('div1');
    div1.onmouseover = function(){
    alert('Function launched!');
    };
</script>

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<script>
  var div1 = document.getElementById('div1');
  var div2 = document.getElementById('div2');
  flag = 0;
  div1.onmouseover = function(event){
      if (event.target === this && flag == 0)
      {
          console.log('ok');
      }
  };
  div1.onmouseout = function(event){
      if (event.target === this)
      {
          flag = 0;
      }
  };

  div2.onmouseover = function(event){
      if (event.target === this)
      {
          flag = 1;
      }
  };

</script>
```

The above code will not allow to listen `mouse over` event of inner div.

Comment: right, its works when the mouse enters the div2 (red -> blue), but not when it escapes div2 (blue -> red )... shame

Comment: Yes.Because it is mouseover event not mouseout event.Then you should right mouse out event also

Comment: No, there is a misundersanting. I don't want event to be launched when (blue -> red ) or (red -> blue) but only ( outside -> red)

Comment: Year, it is. Thanks. So i need to write an event on each element included in div1. I was looking for a solution which only involves div1, because easier to implement on a code but it's fine!

Comment: this shouldnt be perfect answer but hop you would have gt hind.Run your brain nervs :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to stop the event propagation by using stopPropagation().

```
function myEventHandler(e)
 {
if (!e)
  e = window.event;

//IE9 & Other Browsers
if (e.stopPropagation) {
  e.stopPropagation();
}
//IE8 and Lower
else {
  e.cancelBubble = true;
}
}
```

Comment: This solution sounds good but it doesn't work.. I don't know why, it have implemented it [there](http://jsfiddle.net/6pTKm/4/)